# IntelliJ show "always true" hint but not "always false" for instanceof

Tags: java, oop, intellij-idea, instanceof

So, I use IntelliJ IDEA to program in Java, and I was experimenting with the keyword `instanceof` and my code looked eventually like this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        One one = new One();
        One two = new Two();

        if (one instanceof Two) 
        {
            System.out.println(one);
        }

        if (two instanceof Two) 
        {
            System.out.println(one);
        }

    }
}

class One { }

class Two extends One { }
```

IntelliJ gives me at the `two instanceof Two` line a hint "[...] is allways true", but for `one instanceof Two` IntelliJ doesn't give me a "[...] is always false" hint. Does anyone know why?

Comment: I think only an IDEA contributor will be able to answer this. The description of this inspection in the preferences doesn't say much and I wasn't able to find anything else online.

Comment: I agree to the other comment. You are lucky for the intellij developer to answer here, but I think your question should rather have been a bug report on their site directly

Comment: @GhostCat well as IDEA Java support is a part of open source IDEA Community, anyone could dig into code and understand why it doesn't work. Though I agree that it's much easier to answer for IDEA developer. Also in bug report nobody would explain *why* it doesn't work currently, so the question would be unanswered.

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer, and upvoted it for that reason. I am just saying, that in general, people should remember that something that is probably a bug on some 3rd party tool... Should probably be reported as bug there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated:** fixed in IDEA 2018.3.

---

(Disclaimer: IntelliJ IDEA developer is here, who is responsible for this feature).

Short answer: because it's not implemented.

When we track an actual type of variable within the data flow analysis, we use a model described by [TypeConstraint](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/4faf2e16cb832ec3bfd0f60883b1bfb22a2dbb13/java/java-analysis-impl/src/com/intellij/codeInspection/dataFlow/TypeConstraint.java#L32) class. It allows us to track the facts of two kinds: 1) if variable actual type is instanceof something and 2) if variable actual type is not instanceof something. Having these facts we can infer always true/always false instanceof in many cases E.g.:

```
void test(Object foo) {
  if (foo instanceof String) {
    if (foo instanceof Integer) { 
      // always false: "instanceof String" fact is not compatible 
      // with "instanceof Integer"
    }
  }
}
```

Or

```
void test(Object foo) {
  if (!(foo instanceof Number)) {
    if (foo instanceof Integer) { 
      // always false: "not instanceof Number" fact is not compatible 
      // with "instanceof Integer"
    }
  }
}
```

However for your case this model is not enough. We need to extend it to track the exact type of variable. In your code we track that `one` is `instanceof One` (which is compatible with `instanceof Two` fact), despite from the `new` expression we could know more precise type information that `one` is `exactly One`. This is not often usable, because in most of the cases (variable is method parameter, variable is returned from method, variable is assigned from field, array element, cast expression etc.) we cannot know whether the type is exact or subtype, so the current model is completely satisfactory. I can imagine only two cases where `exactly One` fact tracking is useful: the `new` expression (like in your case) and after comparison like `obj.getClass() == Xyz.class`.

I think, it's a reasonable feature to implement. I already thought about this, but as somebody else besides me also cares, I filed [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-195220), so you can track it.